# SP slow on powerful server, but quick locally (both from SSMS)

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-tuning

I have inherited a large and slow stored procedure and it's giving me a nightmare:

I have SQL Server 2008 installed on my desktop with a copy of the production db.  I am running everything from SSMS and I have tried straight SQL and SP.  Time for Sp vs SQL is close enough to the same to not worry unduly about - its the time of local vs server that's concering me.

```
Local:
2Ghz dual-core
4Gb RAM
SQL 2008 Sp1
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (Intel X86)   
Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) 

Server:
2Ghz dual-core
4Gb RAM
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2573.0 (X64)   
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 <X64> (Build 3790: Service Pack 2) (VM)
```

When I run the sproc "locally", it takes around 6 seconds to complete.

When I run the sproc against the server, it takes around 25 minutes to complete!!!

[Total inserts = 45,500]

I have tried to tune the SP as much as I can and avoided parameter sniffing but not sure WHY this should be SO much slower on a pretty much equivalent machine (I know SQL Server version is slightly different, but can't see whjy it would make THAT much difference?)

I know the SP isn't fantastic, but if it runs in 6 seconds locally, then its not total pants!  If it took 60 seconds on the server then that would still be fine.  There are 15 calls to this SP...so 15*0:06 is acceptable...15*25:00 is not!

Server has a pretty low load on it when these SP's are not running, and around 50% CPU when they are in progress (one core 100%?).  Locally CPU never gets above 25%.

---

Apols for posting the whole SP...but can't see how else to show what its doing in case there is an option that can be set to improve things :(

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoadProfitabilitySummaryByCustomer] 
    @inCustomerType char(2),
    @inClearTable int = 0,
    @inStartNum int,
    @inEndNum int
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
    BEGIN
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    DECLARE @customers TABLE (
        CUSNUM CHAR(6) DEFAULT 0
        ,IILQAR DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,IILUSD DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,IILGPB DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,IILEUR DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,IILKWD DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,IILOTH DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,IILMTD DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,IILYTD DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,TCQAR DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,TCUSD DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,TCGPB DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,TCEUR DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,TCKWD DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,TCOTH DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,TCMTD DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        ,TCYTD DECIMAL(20,5) DEFAULT 0
        )

    DECLARE @CustomerType char(2)
    DECLARE @ClearTable int
    DECLARE @StartNum int
    DECLARE @EndNum int

    SET @CustomerType = @inCustomerType
    SET @ClearTable = @inClearTable
    SET @StartNum = @inStartNum
    SET @EndNum = @inEndNum

    DECLARE @sCustomerNumber char(6)

    DECLARE @iDaysInMonth decimal
    DECLARE @iDaysInYear decimal
    DECLARE @dAvgCostQAR DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dAvgCostUSD DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dAvgCostGBP DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dAvgCostEUR DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dAvgCostKWD DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dAvgCostOTH DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dAvgCostTOT DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTIIntIncLnsQAR DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTIIntIncLnsUSD DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTIIntIncLnsGBP DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTIIntIncLnsEUR DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTIIntIncLnsKWD DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTIIntIncLnsOTH DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTIIntIncLnsTOT DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTIIntIncLnsYTD DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTITradeCommQAR DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTITradeCommUSD DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTITradeCommGBP DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTITradeCommEUR DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTITradeCommKWD DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTITradeCommOTH DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTITradeCommTOT DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dTITradeCommYTD DECIMAL(20,5)
    DECLARE @dtMaxDate varchar(30)

    DECLARE @iReportYear int
    DECLARE @START_DATE datetime
    DECLARE @FIRST_MONTH datetime
    DECLARE @END_MONTH datetime
    DECLARE @iNumMonths int
    DECLARE @iNumDaysToday int

    INSERT INTO @customers (CUSNUM)
        SELECT DISTINCT CUSNUM
            FROM EQPRF_SUMMARY
            WHERE CUSTYP = @CustomerType
                AND CUSNUM >= @StartNum
                AND CUSNUM < @EndNum
            GROUP BY CUSNUM

    UPDATE @customers
    SET IILQAR = t2.Amount
    FROM @customers c INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT CUSNUM,
                -SUM(ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(20,5),t.TOTALMTDLCY),0)) as Amount
            FROM TI_INTINCLOANS t
            WHERE t.CCY = 'IILQAR'
                AND t.LINEID = 'LN17'
            GROUP BY t.CUSNUM
        ) AS t2
        ON c.CUSNUM = t2.CUSNUM

    UPDATE @customers
    SET IILUSD = t2.Amount
    FROM @customers c INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT CUSNUM,
                -SUM(ISNULL(CONVERT(decimal(20,5),t.TOTALMTDLCY),0)) as Amount
            FROM TI_INTINCLOANS t
            WHERE t.CCY = 'IILUSD'
                AND t.LINEID = 'LN17'
            GROUP BY t.CUSNUM
        ) AS t2
        ON c.CUSNUM = t2.CUSNUM

    --REPEAT FOR 14 OTHER CRITERIA  

    IF (@ClearTable = 1)
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysindexes WHERE name = 'IX_GROUP_ACCT') DROP INDEX IX_GROUP_ACCT ON PROFITABILITY_SUMMARY

            TRUNCATE TABLE [PROFITABILITY_SUMMARY]

            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysindexes WHERE name = 'IX_GROUP_ACCT')
            CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_GROUP_ACCT
            ON dbo.PROFITABILITY_SUMMARY(CUST_TYPE,GROUP_CODE,ACCOUNT)
            WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90,PAD_INDEX = ON);  
        END

    IF MONTH(getdate())= 1 SET @iReportYear = YEAR(DATEADD(m,-1,getdate()))  -- get last month's year
    ELSE SET @iReportYear = YEAR(getdate())

    SET @START_DATE = CAST('1/1/'+cast(@iReportYear as varchar(4)) as datetime) --first day of report year (If Jan, it's last year)
    SET @FIRST_MONTH = DATEADD(day,-DAY(getdate())+1,getdate())--first day of current month
    SET @END_MONTH = DATEADD(day,-1,@FIRST_MONTH)--determine last day of the previous month
    SET @FIRST_MONTH = DATEADD(M,-1,@FIRST_MONTH)--reset to first day of the previous month
    SET @FIRST_MONTH = CAST(FLOOR( CAST( @FIRST_MONTH AS FLOAT ) ) AS DATETIME) --TRUNCATE HOURS
    SET @END_MONTH = CAST(FLOOR( CAST( @END_MONTH AS FLOAT ) ) AS DATETIME) --TRUNCATE HOURS

    SELECT TOP 1 
        @dAvgCostQAR = AVGCOSTQAR
        ,@dAvgCostUSD = AVGCOSTUSD
        ,@dAvgCostGBP = AVGCOSTGBP
        ,@dAvgCostEUR = AVGCOSTEUR
        ,@dAvgCostKWD = AVGCOSTKWD
        ,@dAvgCostOTH = AVGCOSTOTH
        ,@dAvgCostTOT = AVGCOSTTOT
    FROM dbo.PRFCOSTF

    SET @dtMaxDate = (select top 1 s.txnstmp from EQPRF_SUMMARY s)
    SELECT @iDaysInMonth = dbo.ufn_GetDaysInMonth(CAST(@dtMaxDate as datetime))
    SELECT @iDaysInYear = 360
    SET @iNumDaysToday = (DATEDIFF(dd, @START_DATE, @END_MONTH)+1)

    DECLARE CustomerCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
        FOR
        SELECT CUSNUM
        FROM @customers

    OPEN CustomerCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM CustomerCursor 
        INTO @sCustomerNumber

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

        SELECT 
            @dTIIntIncLnsQAR = c.IILQAR
            ,@dTIIntIncLnsUSD = c.IILUSD
            ,@dTIIntIncLnsGBP = c.IILGPB
            ,@dTIIntIncLnsEUR = c.IILEUR
            ,@dTIIntIncLnsKWD = c.IILKWD
            ,@dTIIntIncLnsOTH = c.IILOTH
            ,@dTIIntIncLnsTOT = c.IILMTD
            ,@dTIIntIncLnsYTD = c.IILYTD
            ,@dTITradeCommQAR = c.TCQAR
            ,@dTITradeCommUSD = c.TCUSD
            ,@dTITradeCommGBP = c.TCGPB
            ,@dTITradeCommEUR = c.TCEUR
            ,@dTITradeCommKWD = c.TCKWD
            ,@dTITradeCommOTH = c.TCOTH
            ,@dTITradeCommTOT = c.TCMTD
            ,@dTITradeCommYTD = c.TCYTD
        FROM @customers c
        WHERE c.CUSNUM = @sCustomerNumber

    INSERT INTO PROFITABILITY_SUMMARY
            SELECT SORT_ORDER = 1, LINE_NO = 'LN01', RPT_DATE=cast(TXNSTMP as datetime),
                LINE_TITLE='Month Loans Outstanding', 
                ACCOUNT = RTRIM(CUSNUM),
                CUST_TYPE = RTRIM(CUSTYP),
                GROUP_CODE = (CASE
                                WHEN RTRIM(CUSGRP) IS NULL OR RTRIM(CUSGRP)='' THEN LEFT(CUSNAME,3)+'--'+RTRIM(CUSNUM)
                                ELSE RTRIM(CUSGRP)
                                END),
                PARENT_COUNTRY = RTRIM(CUSNAP),
                RM_CODE = RTRIM(CUSACO),
                RM_NAME = RTRIM(CUSRNAM),
                CUST_NAME = RTRIM(CUSNAME),
                RISK_CODE = RTRIM(CUSRSKE),
                QAR = ISNULL((SELECT CAST(CURDLAMT AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
              where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='QAR'),0),
                USD = ISNULL((SELECT CAST(CURDLAMT AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
              where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='USD'),0),
                GBP = ISNULL((SELECT CAST(CURDLAMT AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
              where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='GBP'),0),
                EUR = ISNULL((SELECT CAST(CURDLAMT AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
              where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='EUR'),0),
                KWD = ISNULL((SELECT CAST(CURDLAMT AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
              where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='KWD'),0),
                OTHER = ISNULL((SELECT sum(CAST(CURDLAMT AS DECIMAL(20,5))) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
              where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY NOT IN ('QAR', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'KWD')),0),
                TOTAL = SUM(CAST(CURDLAMT AS DECIMAL(20,5))),
                YTD = 0
              FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY] where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber
              GROUP BY CUSNUM,CUSTYP,CUSGRP,CUSNAP,CUSACO,CUSRNAM,CUSNAME,CUSRSKE,TXNSTMP

            UNION ALL
                SELECT SORT_ORDER = 2,LINE_NO = 'LN02', RPT_DATE=cast(TXNSTMP as datetime),
                    LINE_TITLE ='Average Loans Outstanding', 
                    ACCOUNT = RTRIM(CUSNUM),
                    CUST_TYPE = RTRIM(CUSTYP),
                GROUP_CODE = (CASE
                                WHEN RTRIM(CUSGRP) IS NULL OR RTRIM(CUSGRP)='' THEN LEFT(CUSNAME,3)+'--'+RTRIM(CUSNUM)
                                ELSE RTRIM(CUSGRP)
                                END),
                    PARENT_COUNTRY = RTRIM(CUSNAP),
                    RM_CODE = RTRIM(CUSACO),
                    RM_NAME = RTRIM(CUSRNAM),
                    CUST_NAME = RTRIM(CUSNAME),
                    RISK_CODE = RTRIM(CUSRSKE),
                    QAR = ISNULL((SELECT CAST(LNAVGMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='QAR'),0),
                    USD = ISNULL((SELECT CAST(LNAVGMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='USD'),0),
                    GBP = ISNULL((SELECT CAST(LNAVGMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='GBP'),0),
                    EUR = ISNULL((SELECT CAST(LNAVGMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='EUR'),0),
                    KWD = ISNULL((SELECT CAST(LNAVGMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='KWD'),0),
                    OTHER = ISNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(LNAVGMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY NOT IN ('QAR', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'KWD')),0),
                    TOTAL = SUM(CAST(LNAVGMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))),
                    YTD = SUM(CAST(LNAVGYTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))
                  FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY] where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber
                  GROUP BY CUSNUM,CUSTYP,CUSGRP,CUSNAP,CUSACO,CUSRNAM,CUSNAME,CUSRSKE,TXNSTMP
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            --THERE ARE 32 LINES IN TOTAL...ALL FOLLOWING ROUGHLY SAME PATTERN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            UNION ALL
                SELECT SORT_ORDER = 32,LINE_NO = 'GRANTOTAL',RPT_DATE=cast(TXNSTMP as datetime),
                    LINE_TITLE ='Total Income', 
                    ACCOUNT = RTRIM(CUSNUM),
                    CUST_TYPE = RTRIM(CUSTYP),
                GROUP_CODE = (CASE
                                WHEN RTRIM(CUSGRP) IS NULL OR RTRIM(CUSGRP)='' THEN LEFT(CUSNAME,3)+'--'+RTRIM(CUSNUM)
                                ELSE RTRIM(CUSGRP)
                                END),
                    PARENT_COUNTRY = RTRIM(CUSNAP),
                    RM_CODE = RTRIM(CUSACO),
                    RM_NAME = RTRIM(CUSRNAM),
                    CUST_NAME = RTRIM(CUSNAME),
                    RISK_CODE = RTRIM(CUSRSKE),
                    QAR = @dTITradeCommQAR+@dTIIntIncLnsQAR+ISNULL((SELECT CAST(SUSINTMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)) + CAST(INTINCMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))- cast(COSTLNMTD as DECIMAL(20,5))+cast(COSTDPMTD as DECIMAL(20,5)) - CAST(INTEXPMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(LNFEEMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(OTRINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(EXCHINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='QAR'),0),
                    USD = @dTITradeCommUSD+@dTIIntIncLnsUSD+ISNULL((SELECT CAST(SUSINTMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)) + CAST(INTINCMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))- cast(COSTLNMTD as DECIMAL(20,5))+cast(COSTDPMTD as DECIMAL(20,5)) - CAST(INTEXPMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(LNFEEMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(OTRINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(EXCHINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='USD'),0),
                    GBP = @dTITradeCommGBP+@dTIIntIncLnsGBP+ISNULL((SELECT CAST(SUSINTMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)) + CAST(INTINCMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))- cast(COSTLNMTD as DECIMAL(20,5))+cast(COSTDPMTD as DECIMAL(20,5)) - CAST(INTEXPMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(LNFEEMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(OTRINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(EXCHINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='GBP'),0),
                    EUR = @dTITradeCommEUR+@dTIIntIncLnsEUR+ISNULL((SELECT CAST(SUSINTMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)) + CAST(INTINCMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))- cast(COSTLNMTD as DECIMAL(20,5))+cast(COSTDPMTD as DECIMAL(20,5)) - CAST(INTEXPMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(LNFEEMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(OTRINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(EXCHINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='EUR'),0),
                    KWD = @dTITradeCommKWD+@dTIIntIncLnsKWD+ISNULL((SELECT CAST(SUSINTMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)) + CAST(INTINCMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))- cast(COSTLNMTD as DECIMAL(20,5))+cast(COSTDPMTD as DECIMAL(20,5)) - CAST(INTEXPMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(LNFEEMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(OTRINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))+CAST(EXCHINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5)) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY='KWD'),0),
                    OTHER=@dTITradeCommOTH+@dTIIntIncLnsOTH+ISNULL((SELECT SUM(CAST(SUSINTMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+ SUM(CAST(INTINCMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))-SUM(CAST(COSTLNMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(COSTDPMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5))) - SUM(CAST(INTEXPMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(LNFEEMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(OTRINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(EXCHINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))) FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY]
                  where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber AND CUSCCY NOT IN ('QAR', 'USD', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'KWD')),0),
                    TOTAL = @dTITradeCommTOT+@dTIIntIncLnsTOT+ SUM(CAST(SUSINTMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(INTINCMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))-SUM(CAST(COSTLNMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(cast(COSTDPMTD as DECIMAL(20,5))) - SUM(CAST(INTEXPMTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(LNFEEMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(OTRINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(EXCHINCMTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5))),
                    YTD = @dTITradeCommYTD+@dTIIntIncLnsYTD+ SUM(CAST(SUSINTYTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(INTINCYTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))-SUM(CAST(COSTLNYTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(cast(COSTDPYTD as DECIMAL(20,5))) - SUM(CAST(INTEXPYTD AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(LNFEEYTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(OTRINCYTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5)))+SUM(CAST(EXCHINCYTD  AS DECIMAL(20,5)))

                  FROM [MISReportInterface].[dbo].[EQPRF_SUMMARY] where CUSNUM=@sCustomerNumber
                GROUP BY CUSNUM,CUSTYP,CUSGRP,CUSNAP,CUSACO,CUSRNAM,CUSNAME,CUSRSKE,TXNSTMP
            ORDER BY 1

        FETCH NEXT 
            FROM CustomerCursor 
            INTO @sCustomerNumber

        END

    CLOSE CustomerCursor
    DEALLOCATE CustomerCursor

END
```

Comment: Why's this been flagged for close?  Its a legitimate question:  Why would SP run so much slower on server than local?  If there's a reason (code too long?) then please comment and I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: same db (same data in the tables) ?

Comment: Is (VM) for Virtual Machine ?

Comment: Yes, same db (copy of production) and prod on VM.

Comment: Inserting into db may results on a high load of writing on disks. VM was not really goog for high load writing on hardware through their (not an expert) "virtual disk interface". I always choose not to virtualize SQL server when performance is an issue.

Comment: Finally got this onto a non-VM copy of SQL Standard...was slightly slower than my Enterprise edition, but only by a second or so (and that could have been for lots of other reasons)..please could @tschmit007 make this an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: VM Ware causing very slow disk writes.

Same DB on a physical server was very quick.  Same DB on VM server was slow again.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop with no load and the server has a low load.   Way different.   Kick the users off and put both databases in single user mode if you want a fair comparison.

Those inserts need to acquire locks.   Even a low load can be holding a lot of locks.

The other thing to look at is index fragmentation but I bet it can be explained by locks.

If you have active users taking shared locks they are not blocking each other.

But a shared lock will prevent the SP from acquiring an update lock.

A dirty read (no lock) will not block an update lock.

Kick users off and test.  If the time comes down then most likely it is a locking issue.

Comment: Thanks, but tried that.  No users on (other than me) and the tables are read-only anyway to users (its for reporting - so they only have access through SSRS...which I stopped for testing)

Comment: As you expected, Profiler shows a LOT of locks being aquired/released for the inserts...is there any other way of doing this.  e.g. batching up the insert so it does them all under one "lock"?

Comment: If it is a read only table then how are you inserting records.  I explain a shared lock and your response is "read-only anyway".

Comment: "read-only anyway to users"...i.e. they have no way of performing inserts.  This doesn't explain a shared lock to me, it just tells me I may have them.